# how could I send an email reporting URL changed w urlwatch?

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

I'm trying to set some URLs to be watched via SSH on a Debian system. I need to receive an email about URL changed (is this included automatically?), but no way for doing that 'til now.

So I installed urlwatch, imported some URLs /root/.urlwatch/urls.txt and set this cron:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/urlwatch | mail -s "job  changes" mymail@gmail.com`

No error message at all, and no email received.

Weird thing: parameters in the docs does not seem to work. I.e

`urlwatch --list`

gives an:

`urlwatch: error: no such option: --list`

Comment: Run just `urlwatch` in a terminal window without a pipe and see what you get? Does the machine  you are running this `cron` have an active `sendmail` ? Does the user of the `cron` have any mail messages? Else I'd look for a developer forum specific to this, search for solutions there, and if none found, then post a query there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

urlwatch --edit to add the URLs you want to watch.
urlwatch --edit-config to add your email server info. 
Then add urlwatch to a cron job get automated checking. No switches or extra info needed if you populated the other two files ahead of time.